# Is there a way to use a variable in a function from an inner function

Tags: python, list, function

I have a code piece like this:

```
def A():
  def B():
    c.append("hello")
    d = 8

  c = []
  d = 0

  B()

  print(c, d)
```

I get this output:

```
["hello", 0]
```

I want to make function `B` reach `c` and `d` from function `A`. It reaches `c` because it is a `list` but i also want to reach `d` from `B`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could return the value from your inner function, and use it in the outer function. You could also look into variable scope.

Comment: Yes, but i want to do this as easy as possible so nonlocal is easier

Comment: @Just_Me Just not easier to understand or maintain. Especially when your functions are larger than two lines and you do this with more than one variable.

Comment: You could also use a class and make `c` and `d` attributes of this class. Then any method would be allowed to update `c` and `d` without any "magic trick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `d` as [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal). This will make the cell "writable" from within the inner function.

`c` works because you're mutating the object in-place, however Python's "implicit declaration" (assigning to a variable) always declares names *in the local scope*. So when you try to update a non-local or global variable, what happens instead is that a variable of the same name is declared as a function local.

The `global` and `nonlocal` statements override this implicit declaration, and instead declare that the variable(s) of the specified name(s) are respectively global to the module or in some enclosing function scope rather than local to the function. Assignments will then "carry over" to the proper scope rather than implicitly cause the declaration of a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

One easy `Python3` approach would be directly accessing the function's local variable as below.

```
def A():
    def B():
        c.append("hello")
        A.d = 8  # <<

    c = []
    d = 0

    B()
    print(c, A.d)  # <<
A()
```